# Adding Multiple Instances of Google Places on Same Page

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-places

I'm looking to include 2 instances of Google Places auto-complete on the same page. Looking to setup an input for a Pickup Location and an input for a Dropoff Location.

I'm assuming it has to do with the ID of the input element, but even when I changed it to a class, it still wasn't working.

This is what I currently have, and it works for the first field, but I can't figure out how to get a second input field to auto complete, or even show any signs of being anything other than a plain input text field.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var placeSearch,autocomplete;
  function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), { types: [ 'geocode' ] });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      fillInAddress();
    });
  }
  function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in component_form) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = "";
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components.length; j++) {
      var att = place.address_components[j].types[0];
      if (component_form[att]) {
        var val = place.address_components[j][component_form[att]];
        document.getElementById(att).value = val;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<form action="" method="post" name="theform" id="theform">
    <label>Pickup Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="PickupLocation" onfocus="geolocate()" placeholder="Enter your pickup location" id="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" />

    <label>Dropoff Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="DropoffLocation" onfocus="geolocate()" placeholder="Enter your dropoff location" id="autocomplete2" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is simply problem.
You using two IDs "autocomplete" and "autocomplete2"
but initialized only ID "autocomplete".
Try add this code to initialize().

**Javascript**

```
autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete2'), { types: [ 'geocode' ] });
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
  fillInAddress();
});
```

Comment: Ahh, such a stupid thing for me to have missed! This worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 31):

A more dynamic approach. You don't need to initialise your element ids.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('query');

var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};

var autocompletes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], options);
  autocomplete.inputId = inputs[i].id;
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillIn);
  autocompletes.push(autocomplete);
}

function fillIn() {
  console.log(this.inputId);
  var place = this.getPlace();
  console.log(place. address_components[0].long_name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyC0Laj_Wk3kjFM-S8mYljc-WWCeesoDA_M"></script>

<input id="query-0" class="query" type="text"/>
<input id="query-1" class="query" type="text"/>
<input id="query-2" class="query" type="text"/>
```

Comment: The instantiation is dynamic but it's not very flexible. fillIn() needs to work for all instances of your autocomplete. I rather be explicit in this case and instantiate a named var for additional autocompletes.

Comment: @NathanCH I don't really get your comment. Could you provide a jsfiddle to help me understand. I'd be really happy to edit my answer to add more flexibility.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution, but needs jQuery

```js
var autocomplete = {};
  var autocompletesWraps = ['test', 'test2'];

  var test_form = { street_number: 'short_name', route: 'long_name', locality: 'long_name', administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name', country: 'long_name', postal_code: 'short_name' };
  var test2_form = { street_number: 'short_name', route: 'long_name', locality: 'long_name', administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name', country: 'long_name', postal_code: 'short_name' };

  function initialize() {

   $.each(autocompletesWraps, function(index, name) {
   
    if($('#'+name).length == 0) {
     return;
    }

    autocomplete[name] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('#'+name+' .autocomplete')[0], { types: ['geocode'] });
     
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[name], 'place_changed', function() {
     
     var place = autocomplete[name].getPlace();
     var form = eval(name+'_form');

     for (var component in form) {
      $('#'+name+' .'+component).val('');
      $('#'+name+' .'+component).attr('disabled', false);
     }
     
     for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (typeof form[addressType] !== 'undefined') {
        var val = place.address_components[i][form[addressType]];
        $('#'+name+' .'+addressType).val(val);
      }
     }
    });
   });
  }
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      table {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      table td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
  </head>

  <body onload="initialize()">
  
  <div id="test">
    
    <input class="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field street_number" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field route" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field locality" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field postal_code" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<br /><br />
 
<div id="test2"> 
 
    <input class="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
    
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field street_number" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field route" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field locality" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field postal_code" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How I can make this work on cloned elements. which loaded on click of cloned buttons

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't get Joseph's solution to work above, as the second input field would still fill in the first input field, so this is based on his answer with some amendments.

I have two address form on the same page, and they display dynamically depending on the customer's previous selection, so I started by creating a unique id, then add the usual fields.

```
<div id="<?php if( isset( $postcode_context ) && $postcode_context == "collection") { echo "collections-autocomplete-fields";} else {echo "autocomplete-fields";}?>" class="new-address-fields">
    <div class="fields">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="Address1">Building Number/Name *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control field" name="Address1" id="street_number">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="Address2">Address line 1 *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control field" name="Address2" id="route">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="Address2">Address line 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control field" name="Address2" id="route_two">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="Town">Town *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control field" name="Town" id="locality">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="County">County</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control field" name="County" id="administrative_area_level_1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 wideField">
            <label for="Postcode">Postcode *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control field" name="Postcode" id="postal_code">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 wideField">
            <label for="Country">Country *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control field" name="Postcode" id="country">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With jQuery as follows:

```
googlePlaces: function ($context) {
        var placeSearch, autocomplete;
        var componentForm = {
            street_number: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            locality: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
            country: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name'
        };

        var componentForm2 = {
            street_number: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            locality: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
            country: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name'
        };

        function initAutocomplete() {
            // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
            // location types.
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
                (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
                    types: ['geocode'],
                    componentRestrictions: {
                        country: ['UK']
                    }
                });

            autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
                (document.getElementById('collections-autocomplete')), {
                    types: ['geocode'],
                    componentRestrictions: {
                        country: ['UK']
                    }
                });

            // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
            // fields in the form.
            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
            autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress2);
        }

        function fillInAddress() {
            // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            for (var component in componentForm) {
                document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
            }

            // Get each component of the address from the place details
            // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                }
            }
        }

        function fillInAddress2() {
            // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
            var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();
            for (var component in componentForm2) {
                document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
            }

            // Get each component of the address from the place details
            // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (componentForm2[addressType]) {
                    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm2[addressType]];
                    $('#collections-autocomplete-fields #' + addressType).val(val);
                }
            }
        }

        // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
        // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
        function geolocate() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var geolocation = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        center: geolocation,
                        radius: position.coords.accuracy
                    });
                    autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                });
            }
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete);
    }
```

First time answering a question in full on here, so hopefully I have met the criteria.  Thanks to Joseph, who this answer is based on.

Comment: So much for not repeating yourself.

Comment: Indeed, though I've since refactored since moving it to AngularJS.

Answer (score 3):

I have wrote a blog about this here -> https://lindarawson.com/adding-multiple-instances-of-google-places-on-same-page/

I took all of your answers, and made my own answer.

In the loading function of the page:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var autocompletesWraps = ['facility_address', 'source_address'];
      createGeoListeners(autocompletesWraps);
    });
```

Then you have four functions:

```
    function createGeoListeners(autocompletesWraps) {
            var options = {types: ['geocode']};
            var inputs = $('.autocomplete');
            var autocompletes = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], options);
                autocomplete.inputId = inputs[i].id;
                autocomplete.parentDiv = autocompletesWraps[i];
                autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddressFields);
                inputs[i].addEventListener("focus", function() {
                    geoLocate(autocomplete);
                }, false);
                autocompletes.push(autocomplete);
            }
        }
        function fillInAddressFields() {
            $('.googleerror').removeClass('is-valid is-invalid');
            var place = this.getPlace();
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                var val = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                //console.log("address Type " + addressType + " val " + val + " pd " + this.parentDiv);
                $('#'+this.parentDiv).find("."+addressType).val(val);
                $('#'+this.parentDiv).find("."+addressType).attr('disabled', false);
            }
        }
        function geoLocate(autocomplete) {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var geolocation = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        center: geolocation,
                        radius: position.coords.accuracy
                    });
                    autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                });
            }
        }
        function gm_authFailure() { 
            $('.gm-err-autocomplete').addClass('is-invalid');
            swal("Error","There is a problem with the Google Maps or Places API","error");
        };
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, why do you need `autocompletes = []`. It seems not being used anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works but has one problem:

```
var theFields = ['field1','field2','field3','field4'];
function initialize() {
// Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
// to geographical location types.
 for (i=0;i<cityFields.length; i++){

      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById(cityFields[i])),
  { types: ['geocode'] })
  }

// When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
// populate the address fields in the form.
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
fillInAddress();
});
}
```

the only problem for this though is that field2 won't load the script if field1 does not exist on the page. For example, as in my case, the first 2 fields exist on one page, the other 2 exist on another, but the script is added to the header (wordpress header)...

Answer (score 0):

**> This code works for me. Try and let me know.**

```
    // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

var componentForm2 = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autolocation')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

 autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autolocation2')),
      {types: ['geocode']});      

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);   
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

function fillInAddress2() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm2) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Almost worked for me but the result of the search from both fields are being displayed on form 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function initAutocomplete() {
var input = document.getElementById('source');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
                            document.write(searchBox)


var input = document.getElementById('destination');
var searchBox1 = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
                            document.write(searchBox1)
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?  
key=your_palce_api_key&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with multiple autocomplete on one page,
one component created the autocomplete and I had to call it twice

**the problem was: the autocomplete worked only for the first input and not the second**

What solved it for me was: pass as a prop to the component a "uniqueId", and in the component, in the 'place_changed' event listener:

```
    const input = document.getElementById(uId);
    let autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({ "country": "il" });
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => { handlePlaceChange(autocomplete) })
```

I'm currently busy so if anyone needs furher info contact me
shankehat@gmail.com

Answer (score -2):

```
    function initialize() {

      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),

          { types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions:countryRestrict });


      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

        fillInAddress();

      });

      autocomplete2 = new 

    google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete2'), { 
    types: [ 'geocode' ] });

      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {

        fillInAddress();

      });


}
```