# Using google places API twice on same page

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I currently have two inputs like this

```
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" name ="start" size="50"><br>
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" name ="start" size="50"><br>
```

and this javascript

```
function initialize() {

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');

new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);        

}
```

How do I make the second text box also use google places autocomplete? I have been unable to figure this out.

Comment: Give the second input a different id and use the same code. HTML: 

`<input id="searchTextField1" type="text" name ="start" size="50"><br>
<input id="searchTextField2" type="text" name ="start" size="50"><br>`

and **JS**:


`function initialize() {

var input1 = document.getElementById('searchTextField1');
var input2 = document.getElementById('searchTextField2');

new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input1,options);
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2,options);     

}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this does not work, it makes neither field autocomplete.

Comment: You have to add an event listener to both of them. Are you doing that?

Comment: I found another related thread, and possibly a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416058/adding-multiple-instances-of-google-places-on-same-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Multiple Instances of Google Places on Same Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416058/adding-multiple-instances-of-google-places-on-same-page)