# Livewire Multi Step Booking Form clearing Google Map Autocomplete values from input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, google-api

I hope that someone could please help me out with an issue that I have been struggling with for quite some time now after doing a lot of research and implementing different codes and nothing seems to work.

I am using **Livewire Multi Step Booking Form** : https://www.positronx.io/laravel-livewire-wizard-form-tutorial-with-example/

In the first step, first 2 input fields are **Pick Up Location** and **Drop Off Location**. (**Location Restricted to Italy only**)

When I **remove** the Livewire Scripts, the Google Map Autocomplete with full address fills the input field with needed value, but then the **form can't proceed to STEP 2**.

When I **add** the Livewire scripts, then the form works, but **Pick Up Location and Drop Off Location** will **clear** the Autocomplete address and **only submit what was typed before the auto suggest gave the full address**.

I have added **dd($validatedData)**; at the Wizard.php to see what happens when proceeding to STEP 2.

I would really appreciate any support or advice to fix the above mentioned issue.

**Live Test URL** : https://teqcube.com/stackoverflow
**Download Views files with commented code (Trial and Error functions)** : https://teqcube.com/stackoverflow/download/views.zip

**COMPOSER.JSON**

```
"php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
"laravel/framework": "^7.29",
"livewire/livewire": "^2.0",
```

**RESOURCES/VIEWS/LAYOUTS/GENERAL.BLADE.PHP**

```
<body onload="initAutocomplete()">
```

**RESOURCES/VIEWS/DEFAULT.BLADE.PHP**

```
@section('header-scripts')

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initAutocomplete() {
            // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
            // location types.
            autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                (document.getElementById('autocomplete1')), {
                    types: ['geocode']
                });
            
            autocomplete1.setComponentRestrictions(
                {'country': ['it']});

            // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
            // fields in the form.
            // autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
            
            autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                (document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), {
                    types: ['geocode']
                });

            autocomplete2.setComponentRestrictions(
                {'country': ['it']});

            // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
            // fields in the form.
            // autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress2);        
        }
    </script>
    
@endsection
```

**RESOURCES/VIEWS/LIVEWIRE/WIZARD.BLADE.PHP**

```
<div class="row setup-content {{ $currentStep != 1 ? 'display-none' : '' }}" id="step-1">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3> Step 1</h3>
      
      <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416058/adding-multiple-instances-of-google-places-on-same-page -->

      <!-- PICKUP LOCATION -->
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="trip_pickup_location">Pick-up Destination</label>
          <input type="text" wire:model="trip_pickup_location" class="controls autocomplete form-control-lg form-control" id="autocomplete1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Pick-up Destination">
          @error('trip_pickup_location') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
      </div>            

      <!-- DROPOFF LOCATION -->
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="trip_dropoff_location">Drop-off Destination</label>
          <input type="text" wire:model="trip_dropoff_location" class="controls autocomplete form-control-lg form-control" id="autocomplete2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Drop-off Destination">
          @error('trip_dropoff_location') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
      </div>
      
      <!-- PICKUP LOCATION -->
      <!-- <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="trip_pickup_location">Pick-up Destination</label>
        <input type="text" wire:model="trip_pickup_location" onfocus="geolocate()" class="controls autocomplete form-control-lg form-control" id="autocomplete1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Pick-up Destination">
        @error('trip_pickup_location') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
      </div>             -->

      <!-- DROPOFF LOCATION -->
      <!-- <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="trip_dropoff_location">Drop-off Destination</label>
        <input type="text" wire:model="trip_dropoff_location" onfocus="geolocate()" class="controls autocomplete form-control-lg form-control" id="autocomplete2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Drop-off Destination">
        @error('trip_dropoff_location') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
      </div> -->

      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Pickup Date:</label>
          <input type="text" wire:model="trip_pickup_date" class="form-control" id="trip_pickup_date" />
          @error('trip_pickup_date') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Pick Up Time:</label>
          <input type="text" wire:model="trip_pickup_time" class="form-control" id="trip_pickup_time" />
          @error('trip_pickup_time') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Pax Amount:</label>
          <input type="text" wire:model="trip_pax_amount" class="form-control" id="trip_pax_amount" />
          @error('trip_pax_amount') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" wire:click="firstStepSubmit"
          type="button">
          Next
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look, this, using alpine might get you in the right direction. https://forum.laravel-livewire.com/t/wire-ignore-with-google-autocomplete/734

Comment: Hi Louwki, thank you. I will have a look at the link you suggested and hopefully it will solve the problem.

Comment: wire:model.ignore
This did the trick thank you